# Creating a new instance of an object on button push

Tags: c#, runtime, instantiation

It seems like it should be simple enough, but im having trouble wrapping my brain around it. Normally you would declare an object in one of a couple ways

```
ClassName a;
a = new ClassName();
```

or

```
ClassName a = new ClassName();
```

etc...

but since you're explicitly declaring these at compile time i get confused when Im supposed to code this to happen at runtime. What I want to do is have a new instance of the Class instantiated when a button is clicked. But what I'm not grasping here is how is the object name going to be named if this is happening on button click?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even worse, Objects don't have a Name at all.
The variable you are naimg is the reference to the object.

It matters what you decide the object will belong to:

```
void ButtonClick_H1(...)
{
  ClassName a;          //local variable
  a = new ClassName();  // object belongs to this method
}


private  ClassName anObject;   // class field
void ButtonClick_H2(...)
{ 
  anObject = new ClassName();  // object belongs to  'this' Form
}
```

Comment: Im not sure its working the way i think it should. In the class i defined, there is a command to increment an attribute in each constructor: _numberCreated++; I have the form set to instantiated a new object of that class each time it is pressed. I plugged in a messagebox to display the current value of _numberCreated but it doesn't seem to be incrementing

Comment: @Sinaesthetic: Is your `_numberCreated` variable *static*?  The behavior you are describing makes it sound like it is not.  If it is not static, you have a *separate* `_numberCreated` variable for each instance of your class.

Comment: Bingo, Zach. Thats what it was. I was sitting here running through the logic in my head and I was thinking the same thing. It didnt occur to me to make it static. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
public partial class Form1
{
    Classname myClass;

    public void Button1_Click(...)
    {
          myClass = new Classname();
    }
}
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you create the object using the code you showed above, and that will be the new instance of your Class. If you declared a inside the scope of the method it will cease to exist after the method (unless there are external references to it), but if you declare it outside the method as a class variable it will stay until the class is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

In exactly the same way as you would usually name an object.

You need to hook into the button's `Click` event:

`this.Button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Button_Click);`

Then use something like

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ClassName a = new ClassName();
}
```